# Mathematical Induction Hint

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Trying to show that the inequality holds for $$n^2 \le 2^n$$

So far I have: $$\text{Assume }k \text{ is arbitrary. Our inductive hypothesis is: } k^2 \le 2^k \text{. Show this is true for } k+1\\ (k+1)^2 = k^2+2k+1 \\ k^2 < k^2+2k+1$$

Stuck here and wondering if I could get some hints.

Comment: Hint: You know by induction that $k^2 \leqslant 2^k$. That is, $k^2+2k+1 \leqslant 2^k + 2k + 1$. Can you bound more from here?

Comment: Could I say, $2^k +2k+1 \le 2^k \cdot 2^k$? Induction with inequalities isn't my strong suit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof by Induction: Prove that $2^n &gt; n^2$, for all natural numbers greater than or equal to $5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759995/proof-by-induction-prove-that-2n-n2-for-all-natural-numbers-greater-than). Another very similar question here is [Proof by induction that $2^n - 1 > n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042190/602049).

Comment: You can say anything... if you can justify it. To get to $2^k + 2k + 1 \leqslant (2^k)(2^k)$, it suffices to show that $2k+1 \leqslant 2^k$ (can you see why this is?). Can you show that?

Comment: Note @William and Peter P. that proving the right side of an inequality with $2^k \cdot 2^k = 2^{2k}$ doesn't help much since the right side of the inequality to prove for $n = k + 1$ is actually $2^{k + 1} = 2(2^k)$ instead.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I meant $2^k + 2^k$.